# AngularJS select with lot of options - slow rendering

Tags: angularjs

I started exploring AngularJS but wasn't really happy with the time Angular takes to render a select element with huge number of options.

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/lCeqaG91PeHjltT9AhBq?p=preview`
```

The plunker above demonstrates a simple select element with 2000 options takes about a second to render.

Any help in reducing the screen rendering time is appreciated.

Thanks.

================= Update ======================

On adding two more select elements, the screen rendering time got tripled.

Comment: My guess would be that you are using an old browser? It's ~0.06s for me.

Comment: Hi Ineetho, I have tested the same in IE11 and FF 31.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try storing it in a local variable while populating the array? This will prevent any UI rendering until the whole list is populated.

```
  var employeeList = [];
  for (var i=0; i<2500; i++) 
  {
     employeeList.push({id:i,name:"Employee - "+i});
  }
  $scope.employeeList = employeeList;
```

Comment: Hi Chris.. that was indeed a very good suggestion. Screen rendering time is reduced by 100 ms.. However, I still felt angular taking more time to render the screen. My concern was if we have multiple select elements like that on screen, the screen rendering time would be more.

Comment: This will not prevent any UI from rendering. In this code, and the original code, no UI will be rendered and no other JS code will be processed while this loop is running.
The only efficiency this code might provide is very minor, if any: local variables are accessed faster than global variables, and presumably this local variable might be accessed quicker than $scope.

Comment: @HankScorpio, I thought there might be a watch based on a hidden getter/setter to scope properties that's responsible for rendering the template. The digest cycle docs is not the best, does angular use a timer/delay to wait before updating the views?

Comment: It probably does, but even if it didn't, this is a single-threaded application. There's nothing except for cutting the power to your computer, or in some cases forcibly closing the browser, that will interrupt the application thread in order to update the UI. That would be hugely inefficient and would probably cause most applications to grind to a halt and crash the browser. There's currently no way for angular to interrupt and do something at the moment you add something to an array, even if it's on the scope.

Comment: With ES6 and angular 2.0 (neither of which is quite ready yet) it will be possible to do something like that using "proxies". If the angular team decides to make use of proxies, they can dynamically implement a setter for any object on the scope (or whatever the 2.0 equivalent will be). With setters, code can be run when a property is assigned, but it still wouldn't update any view at that time (because: hugely inefficent), and certainly not when modifying the _contents_ of an array. The angular team is very focused on high performance, so at most they might use it to mark a property as dirty.